# Java and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner programmer and i understand this pseudocode will have many errors, and that is why i came here to ask for help! I know i'm not passing anything i just can't seem to wrap my head around how to get them there. I'm also not sure if while gather input i'm using alter and prompt correctly. In the display function, the spacing is necessary for when it will be displayed. Corrections and explanations are greatly appreciated. Any help would be amazing as i cannot wrap my head around how to formulate this. (**NOTE: this is for java**)

Instructions for exercise:

*Last year, a local college implemented rooftop gardens as a way to promote energy efficiency and save money.  Write a program that will allow the user to enter the energy bills from January to June prior to going green.  Next, allow the user to enter the energy bills from January to June after going green.  The program should calculate the energy difference and display the 6 months’ worth of data, along with the savings.*

***Hint:
Create 4 global arrays of size 6 each.  The first array (notGreenCost) will store the first 6 months of energy costs, the second array (goneGreenCost) will store the 6 months after going green, and the third array (savings) will store the difference.  Also, create an array (months) that stores the month names***

The pseudocode so far:

```
//Add statements to declare the global array variables
Declare Real notGreenCost[6]
Declare Real goneGreenCost[6]
Declare Real savings[6]
Declare Real months[6]

Module main()
    //Declare local variables
    Declare String endProgram = “no”

    Call initMonths()
    While endProgram == “no”
        //Module calls
        Call getNotGreen()
        Call getGoneGreen()
        Call energySaved()
        Call displayInfo()

        Display “Do you want to end the program (enter yes or no):”
        Input endProgram
        While endProgram<>”no” AND endProgram<>”yes”
            Display “Please enter a value of yes or no: ”
            Input endProgram
        End While
    End While
End Module

Module initMonths()
    months = “January”, “February”, “March”, “April”, “May”, “June”
End Module

Module getNotGreen()
    //Add statements to retrieve 6 months of info and save to the array
Set counter = 0
For counter < 6
    Display “Enter NOT GREEN energy costs for”, months[counter]
    Input notGreenCosts[counter]
    Set counter = counter + 1
End For
End Module

Module getGoneGreen()
    //Add statements to retrieve 6 months of info and save to the array
Set counter = 0
For counter < 6
    Input goneGreenCosts[counter]
    Set counter = counter + 1
End For 
End Module

Module energySaved()
    //Add statements to calculate 6 months of savings and save to the array
Set counter = 0
While counter < 6
        Set savings[counter] = notGreenCost[counter] – goneGreenCost[counter]
         Set counter = counter + 1
End While
End Module
Module displayInfo()
    //Add statements to display results as shown above
Set counter = 0
While counter < 6
    Display “Information for”, months[counter]
    Display “Savings $”, savings[counter]
    Display “Not Green Costs $”, notGreenCost[counter]
    Display “Gone Green Costs $”, goneGreenCost[counter]
End While
End Module
```

Comment: You talk about [tag:java] in the question, but have tagged it [tag:javascript] and your code example is in [tag:pseudocode]. Pick one!

Comment: sorry im still new here, can i change the tags?

Comment: Never mind i found out how to edit it! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Rather than "am I doing right?", "what am I doing wrong here?", ... which is just too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A{

    public static int []PriorGreen = new int[6];
        public static int []AfterGreen = new int[6];
        public static String []month = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","April","May","June"};

    static void PriorG()
{
    System.out.println(" Enter Cost for Prior Green Month's Below !!!");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
          System.out.println("  Please enter cost for "+month[i]);
          PriorGreen[i]=in.nextInt();

        }
}

static void AfterG()
{
    System.out.println(" Enter Cost for After Green Month's Below !!!");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
          System.out.println("  Please enter cost for "+month[i]);
          AfterGreen[i]=in.nextInt();

        }
}
static void energySaved()
{
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

          System.out.println(" Energy saved in "+month[i]+" is "+(PriorGreen[i]-AfterGreen[i]));


        }
}
static void display()
{
              System.out.println("Prior Green       "+"After Green    "+ "Savings");
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

          System.out.println(PriorGreen[i]+"                  "+AfterGreen[i]+"                  "+(PriorGreen[i]-AfterGreen[i]));


        }
}

    public static void main(String []args)
    {

        PriorG();
        AfterG();
        energySaved();

        display();      

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see only one small oversight in your pseudocode. In your `displayInfo` you forgot to increment your counter. You should add `Set counter = counter + 1` inside the while loop.

One other thing I notice is that you have a loop that runs the core logic until the user responds "no": 
`While endProgram == “no”` which is not in your requirements. I don't think it's a bad thing necessarily but it would depend on your instructor and whether they would mark you down for that.

I suggest you start writing your Java code and update your post if you run into problems for which you can't find a solution.